# Corn already has tassel but not female flowers

Tags: pollination, corn

I have 5 corn plants growing on my garden, one of them (the tallest) already has a tassel, and today I moved it a bit and saw pollen falling from it. But the plant has no female flowers to pollinate.

Should I try to collect and save the pollen for when the female flowers show up? Or will there still be pollen when they show up?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to bother with pollination and timing.  Corn female flowers are tough to notice. But they are there.  A corn plant produces both male and female reproductive organs.

You are either too eager to see corn cobs growing or...you might have fertilized with a high Nitrogen formula that is higher in Nitrogen percentage than the Phosphorous and Potassium.  This will most certainly ruin your chances to produce ears of corn, they are reproductive organs.  Too much nitrogen in relation to phosphorus and potassium will generate vegetative growth...lots of healthy leaves and stalks but little reproductive growth which is what the ears of corn are as well as the tassels.

Sending an article about the plant's botany to you...those 'female flowers' are there but either you don't know what to look for or you've used too much Nitrogen in relation to the P and the K.

How many days since germination has it been?  What brand of corn did you plant, how did you plant it and when did you plant it in what zone?  Where do you live?

[Basics about sweet corn](https://www.botanical-online.com/english/maize.htm)

[anatomy of corn](https://www.thoughtco.com/the-anatomy-of-corn-419204)